# Is "Fitter Happier" by Radiohead referring to the perceived futility and "entrapment" of the middle-class suburbia lifestyle?

Tags: song-lyrics, radiohead, ok-computer

"Fitter Happier" by Radiohead has the following lyrics:

> Fitter, happier
> More productive
> Comfortable
> Not drinking too much
> Regular exercise at the gym, three days a week
> Getting on better with your associate employee contemporaries
> At ease
> Eating well, no more microwave dinners and saturated fats
> A patient, better driver
> A safer car, baby smiling in back seat
> Sleeping well, no bad dreams
> No paranoia
> Careful to all animals, never washing spiders down the plughole
> Keep in contact with old friends, enjoy a drink now and then
> Will frequently check credit at moral bank, hole in wall
> Favours for favours, fond but not in love
> Charity standing orders on sundays, ring-road supermarket
> No killing moths or putting boiling water on the ants
> Car wash, also on sundays
> No longer afraid of the dark or midday shadows, nothing so ridiculously teenage
>  and desperate
> Nothing so childish
> At a better pace, slower and more calculated
> **No chance of escape**
> Now self-employed
> **Concerned, but powerless**
> An empowered and informed member of societ, pragmatism not idealism
> Will not cry in public
> Less chance of illness
> Tires that grip in the wet, shot of baby strapped in backseat
> A good memory
> Still cries at a good film
> Still kisses with saliva
> **No longer empty and frantic**
> Like a cat
> Tied to a stick
> That's driven into
> Frozen winter ****, the ability to laugh at weakness
> Calm, fitter, healthier and more productive
> A pig in a cage on antibiotics

Not coincidentally, the entire thing is read in a robotic, synthesized voice. Clearly, this is referring to the "deadening," entrapping effects of the lifestyle in question.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OK_Computer) describes this as follows:

> "Fitter Happier" is a short musique concrète track that consists of sampled musical and background sound and spoken-word lyrics recited by a synthesised voice from the Macintosh SimpleText application. The voice belongs to "Fred", a synthesised voice included with Macintosh computers. Yorke wrote the lyrics "in ten minutes" after a period of writer's block while the rest of the band were playing. He described the words as a checklist of slogans for the 1990s, and he considered the lyrics "the most upsetting thing I've ever written", and said it was "liberating" to give the words to a neutral-sounding computer voice. Among the samples in the background is an audio loop from the 1975 film Three Days of the Condor. The band considered using "Fitter Happier" as the album's opening track, but decided the effect was off-putting.
>
> Steve Lowe called the song "penetrating surgery on pseudo-meaningful corporations' lifestyles" with "a repugnance for prevailing yuppified social values". Among the loosely connected imagery of the lyrics, Footman identified the song's subject as "the materially comfortable, morally empty embodiment of modern, Western humanity, half-salaryman, half-Stepford Wife, destined for the metaphorical farrowing crate, propped up on Prozac, Viagra and anything else his insurance plan can cover." Sam Steele called the lyrics "a stream of received imagery: scraps of media information, interspersed with lifestyle ad slogans and private prayers for a healthier existence. It is the hum of a world buzzing with words, one of the messages seeming to be that we live in such a synthetic universe we have grown unable to detect reality from artifice."

Is this song comparable to "Hotel California" in a way - you can check out any time you like, but you can never leave ("No chance of escape")? Or am I missing the point?